# Semicontinuity w.r.t. weak convergence of probability measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, continuity, weak-convergence

Let $(S, \mathcal{S})$ be a Polish space and consider the space $\mathcal{P}(S)$ of all Borel probability measures on $S$ endowed with the topology of weak convergence of measures. We know that if $f:S\to\mathbb{R}$ is continous and bounded then the map $$\nu\in\mathcal{P}(S) \to \int f d\nu\in\mathbb{R}$$ is continous. What about (upper/lower) semicontinuity? Is there a weaker condition on a continous $f$ that ensures (upper/lower) semicontinuity of the integral operator?
Thanks to anyone that will help!

Comment: If $f$ is lower semicontinuous and bounded from below then $\mu\mapsto \int f\mu$ is lower semicontinuous. Inn fact $\mu_\alpha\Rightarrow\mu$ iff $\liminf_\alpha\int f\mu_\alpha\geq \int f\,d\mu$ for all l.s.c $f$ bounded from below.

Comment: I see, thanks! Would you know if we can say something about a $f$ for which $\int e^{\lambda f} d\mu < +\infty$ for every $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @filk: the least you can say is that $\mu\mapsto \int e^{\lambda f}\,d\mu$ is l.s.c for $f$ continuous since the map $\phi(x)=e^{\lambda f(x)}$ is continuous and bounded below.